# When does JNI's GetByteArrayElements return a null terminated string?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I intend to use an array of bytes as a C string.

I am interested in both the zero-length and non-zero length conditions.

Comment: Your question is really unclear, return a null terminated string or return null?

Comment: Byte array does not care about null termination. You can simply allocate an array of *strlen()+1* bytes. But why would you do this? Java cannot *cast* byte[] to String. You can use direct ByteBuffer instead

Answer (score 0):

It returns the byte elements of the array. If that happens to be a null-terminated string because of what the application put into the array, you have a null-terminated string. Neither Java nor JNI cares about null termination.